# Determining Sensor Calibration Method

Tags: sensor, calibration, linearity

How to calibrate a sensor that can be affected by humidity? For example MQ-135 as gas sensor (NOx, CO, etc.). According to the datasheet, there are two different curves for the sensor response when exposed to environments with air humidity at 33%RH and 85%RH [Hanwei MQ-135 datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1132552/HANWEI/MQ135.html). I can calibrate sensor using linear regression equation by keeping humidity constant and change gasses concentration. However, I need to continuously seek the linear regression values as humidity changes. How can this be done automatically? Are there logarithmic or other formulations for such cases? I'm interested in utilizing ANN, but the journals I've read lack details on the formulation and technical programming used. Most of them only outline the basic concepts and swiftly transition to percentages or performance graphs among the ANNs used for calibration [journal example](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348202107_Calibrations_of_Low-Cost_Air_Pollution_Monitoring_Sensors_for_CO_NO2_O3_and_SO2).